# String comparison that ignores special unicode charaters

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, string-comparison, character-set

I have a table with city names in various languages. These names often contain characters such as `é`, `ü` etc. I am building a search function so that a user can search for a name, but I would like this to ignore all special characters, and treat them as letters from the English 26-letter alphabet instead.

For instance, a query for the name `munchen` should be matched with the value `München`. The query converts both sides of the comparison to case-insensitive 26-letter alphabet, and *then* performs the comparison.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you working with Sybase or SQL Server? What version?

Comment: Sorry, @ZoharPeled. I use SQL Server 2014..

Comment: There are no special characters in Unicode. Especially not the plain-old Latin1 characters. What are you *really* trying to do? Converting everything to English is an attempt to solve that, but it won't work except for some very limited cases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos correct, I didn't even think about that....

Comment: If you use an accent-insensitive collation for example, then Munchen could match München. SQL Server's Full Text Search feature can already handle such matches, no matter the collation. Any search engine for that matter can handle this

Comment: SO itself is an ASP.NET site storing questions and answers in `nvarchar` fiels in SQL Server. It doesn't need any special handling for any kind of text, like Αυτό Εδώ. Unicode just works in both .NET and SQL Server.

Comment: In fact, there's a German User whose user name is [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96). Well, I don't have the time to install a Greek polytonic keyboard, or remember the correct accents, so I just searched for `παντα ρει`, no accents whatsoever and I still got back a list of questions, answers and comments where he's involved

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do not really understand your question. What I am trying to do is a string comparison that does not take diacritics into account.

Comment: @LeeWhite There are no special characters. What you ask works OOTB. Use an accent-insensitive collation for your field and you won't have to change anything. That will cover equality or `LIKE` searches, although `LIKE '%...%'` will always be slow. If you want to search arbitrary text, use SQL Server's Full text search. Or add another search engine like ElasticSearch

Comment: @LeeWhite check [Collation and Unicode Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017). Apart from the UTF8 collation, everything else holds for all SQL Server versions.

Comment: I am currently trying with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, and am not getting the expected result. A string compare between `Munchen` and `München` returns false.

Comment: `AS` means accent *sensitive*. You should use AI, Accent *in*sensitive. The documentation shows how collation is used and how you can override it with the `COLLATE` keyword. Using `COLLATE` will prevent the use of indexes that don't match this collation though - collation affects ordering, not just matching, and indexes depend that.

Answer (score 2):

Those characters aren't special in any way. Matching and ordering is affected by a column's collation - this specifies the sorting order and which characters match.

A collation can be case-sensitive or not, which specifies whether `Mary` is considered equal to `mary`. It can also be *accent* sensitive or not, which specifies whether `Munchen` is equal to `München` or not.

To match `Munchen` with  `München`, all that's needed is to use an Accent Insensitive collation for that column, eg :

```
create table Cities (
    id int identity primary key,
    Name nvarchar(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI ,
    INDEX IX_Cities_NAME (Name)
)

insert into Cities (Name)
values ('London'), ('München'), ('Munchen')

select * 
from Cities 
where Name = N'mUnchen'
```

The result is :

```
Name
--------
München
Munchen
```

I didn't make `Name` a primary key because I wouldn't be able to insert both `München` and `Munchen`, I'd get a primary key violation